# Why does VALUES inside FILTER result in reinstating the filter?

Tags: powerbi, dax

In CALCULATE, the VALUES usually returns a single column table containing the distinct values, while respecting the filter context.

However when used inside FILTER, in CALCULATE, the VALUES results in reinstating the filter. What is this concept?

For example: VALUES can be used for reinstate the filter removed by REMOVEFILTERS.

Comment: Can you give an example?

Comment: For example: VALUES can be used for reinstate the filter removed by REMOVEFILTERS.

Comment: Writing out an actual measure was what I had in mind.